# I'm having issue with changing the text color of the nav-links in my nav. Any Help would be appreciated

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add color to the text that is inside of my links-wrapper. Whenever I try to add a color of #cbcbcb to my entire navigation-wrapper it just doesn't work. I've tried using !important next to the color and no changes were made. I've also tried moving it to my links-wrapper and still no result.

```css
.navigation-wrapper {
    color: #cbcbcb ;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px 10px 35px 5px;
    background-color: black;
    }

    .navigation-wrapper > .left-column {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    }

    .navigation-wrapper > .left-column img {
    align-items: top;
    width: 175px;
    padding: 30px 50px 10px 15px;
    }

    .navigation-wrapper > .center-column {
    display: flex;
    padding: 50px 30px 10px 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    }

     .navigation-wrapper > .center-column > .links-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .navigation-wrapper > .center-column > .links-wrapper > .nav-link {
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="navigation-wrapper">

            <div class="left-column">
                 <img src="Logos/codepen-wordmark-display-inside- 
     white@10x.png"alt="Logo">
            </div>


            <div class="center-column">
                <div class="links-wrapper">

                    <div class="nav-link">
                        <a href="pens.html">Pens</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-link">
                        <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-link">
                        <a href="posts.html">Posts</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-link">
                        <a href="collections.html">Collections</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-link">
                        <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                            <a href="spark.html">Spark</a>
                        </div>    
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to change the color

```
.nav-link a{
    color:#cbcbcb;
}
```

for changing the color the a tag we must have declare it

here are the resluts
[image]